# masculine/neuter nouns in genitive singular

Tags: noun, genitive, terminology

> Die Farbe des Bus(ses) ist blau.

From what I know either "s" or "es" is added at the end of a masculine/neuter noun in singular form in genitive. This seems to be a special case.

Do you happen to know any other masculine/neuter nouns in genitive singular that have  other terminations besides s/es?

I think "**Schön**en" can fit into this category as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are many nouns that belong to the so-called [*N-Deklination*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#N-Deklination), I decided to create a community wiki. You can add relevant words to the alphabetically ordered lists by editing this answer.

**Masculine**:

- Bär → Bären
- Hase → Hasen
- Held → Helden
- Herr → Herr(e)n
- Mensch → Menschen
- Präsident → Präsidenten
- Rabe → Raben
- Student → Studenten

**Neuter**:

---

TODO: Fürst, Graf, Prinz, Zar, Welf, Schenk, Hirt, Schultheiß, Spatz, Fink, Pfau, Greif, Leu, Narr, Tor, Depp, Geck, Mohr, Oberst, Untertan, Vorfahr, Ahn, Typ, Graph, Tyrann, Kamerad, Bote, Rabe, Löwe, Welpe, Biograph, Digraph, Geograph, Photograph/Fotograf, 
Astrologe, Biologe, Geologe, Neurologe, Philologe, Psychologe, 
Astronom, Ökonom, Taxonom, 
Philosoph, Theosoph, Afghane, Apache, Brite, Chinese, Burmese, Däne, Este, Finne, ...